# How to read server stdout and continue only after message is outputted

Tags: bash, shell, cat, fifo, stdio

Say I have a simple Node.js server like:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req,res) => res.end('foobar'))

server.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify({"listening": 3000}));
});
```

and then with bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

node server.js | while read line; do
  if [[ "$line" == '{"listening":3000}' ]]; then
      :
  fi
done

# here I want to process more crap
```

my goal is to only continue the script after the server has started actually listening for requests. The best thing I can come up with this this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkfifo foo
mkfifo bar

(node server.js &> foo) &

(
while true; do
  cat foo | while read line; do
     if [[ "$line" != '{"listening":3000}' ]]; then
       echo "$line"
       continue;
    fi
    echo "ready" > bar
  done
done
) &

cat bar && {
  # do my thing here?
}
```

is there a less verbose/simpler way to do this? I just want to proceed only when the server is ready and the only good way I know of doing that is to using stdout to print a message and listen for that.

Answer (score 0):

A heavyweight way to do it uses [expect](/questions/tagged/expect)

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env expect

spawn node server.js

set timeout -1
expect {{"listening":3000}}

# now you can process all the crap, but in Expect

interact
```

With bash, you don't need to process the foo file in bash. How about

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

node server.js &> server.out &

# busy wait
while true; do
    grep -q '{"listening":3000}' server.out && break
    sleep 1
done

# continue crap processing
```

You could maybe daemonize the server while you're at it:

```bsh
node server.js </dev/null &> server.out &
disown $!
```

Answer (score 0):

Glenn's answer with `expect` seems to me like a great general solution.

If you want a simpler way, or don't want / can't install expect, here's a smaller version in bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

process() {
    # do your stuff
    echo ok
}

node server.js | ( grep -L '{"listening":3000}' ; process ) &
```

I'm leveraging grep's -L option (-l would work fine too but produce output), making it return as soon as a match is found. Control is then handed to the process function, and you can even continue reading the output if you'd like.

Add `wait` at the end if you don't want the script to return until the server shuts down.